# C# syntax explanation

Tags: c#

Im just beginnig c# programming for win 8 applications. I came across following class definition and I don't understand the get and set lines there. Is that a shortcut for creating standard getters and setters ? Im confused ? Thanks

```
 class MenuItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, its just a shorctut to use Getters & Setters. In c# you dont write getters and setters with methods you do it like this. I suggest you read the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Answer (score 8):

They are [Auto Implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), introduced with C# 3.0.

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required
>   in the property accessors.

For your property:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

It is same as:

```
private string _Title;

public string Title
{
    get { return _Title; }
    set { _Title = value; }
}
```

The compiler will add the backing private field. They are useful in scenarios where no logic is required in get/set for the property. If you want custom rules to be implemented with `set` or `get` then you can't use Auto implemented properties.

Answer (score 1):

"Auto-Implemented Properties" were added in C# 3.0. You can read about them [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). Effectively, the compiler will create a private backing field.